# Secrets Detection in Gitlab does not fail my job

Tags: gitlab

In gitlab, I'm trying to enable secret detection,
I got it to detect vulnerabilities, but it does not fail the job.

this is my ".gitlab-ci.yml" file:

```
include:
  - template: Security/Secret-Detection.gitlab-ci.yml

stages: 
  - test

secret_detection:
  tags:
    - secret
  artifacts:
    reports:
      secret_detection: gl-secret-detection-report.json
  variables:
    SECRET_DETECTION_HISTORIC_SCAN: "true"
```

a part of the log (gl-secret-detection-report.json):

```
      "category": "secret_detection",
      "name": "Stripe",
      "message": "Stripe detected; please remove and revoke it if this is a leak.",
      "severity": "Critical",
      "confidence": "Unknown",
      "raw_source_code_extract": "pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx",
      "scanner": {
        "id": "gitleaks",
        "name": "Gitleaks"
```

but:

[image: Gitlab Secret Detection Job Passed]

running on GitLab Enterprise Edition 14.0.0-ee, Starter plan

how do I get this job to fail on merge requst if it finds something on scan?

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for the answer to this as well and it is (insanely to me) apparently by design, at least on free/premium tiers. I did not understand why the job succeeded when it detected a secret.

Here are some workarounds:

[Fail the pipeline if Secret Detection finds vulnerabilities](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/fail-the-pipeline-if-secret-detection-finds-vulnerabilities/56950)

[GitLab Secret Detection which fails when vulnerabilities were found](https://gist.github.com/halloei/8ea4f1763f16a426f86a56bcf6a97333)

Comment: Confirmed:  the design by GitLab is insecure by design.  To catch that a secret has been checked in and PASS the job is anti-security.

Answer (score 0):

```
secret_detection:
  allow_failure: false
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add some explanation